# How to get Dismissable dragged amount before it's dismissed - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dismissible

The `Dismissible` widget in Flutter gives you an 
`onDismissed: (direction) {....}`
to tell you the direction it was dragged after it has been dismissed. How can I get the direction (or delta) the widget is currently being dragged?

I tried wrapping it in a `GestureDectecor()` which has `onHorizontalDragStart:` etc but it seems to stop the Dismissible from working (i.e. you can't drag it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dismissible` has `onUpdate` callback that reports progress:

```dart
onUpdate: (details) {
  print("onUpdate : ${details.progress}");
},
```

Answer (score 10):

Wrap your `Dismissible` widget inside `Listener` and use the `onPointerMove` callBack.

```
  Listener(
            onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent event) {
              print("Event : $event");
            },
            child: Dismissible(
             ...
             ,
            ),
          )
```

Comment: PointerMoveEvent contains a `delta`. For more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/PointerMoveEvent-class.html